# Java- unable to read image using ImageIO

Tags: java

`displaypic` is `base64` encoded image but `imageio.read(displaypic)` returns `null`.No exception arises

```
byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(DisplayPic);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
try {                           
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);
    File dpPath = new File(DisplayPicturePath);
     if(!dpPath.exists())
        dpPath.createNewFile();
     ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg",dpPath);
} catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is there an exception? What format has the base64-decoded image? Try saving your `ByteArrayInputStream` to a file and see if you can open it with an image viewer...

Comment: Are you trying to decode an already decoded image? `displaypic is base64 decoded image` then `Base64.decodeBase64()`

Comment: is DisplayPic a String or a byte[] ?

Comment: DisplayPic is a string which is base64 encoded..when i decode this string using an online decoder,it is returning me exact picture but the code above returning null..